# Windows is not working after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, grub-efi

I have installed ubuntu 22.04 but my windows is not showing in grub 2.06 menu

When I try doing boot in cmd it says I need a kernel

When I tried doing ls I didn't find any partiotion with EFI folder inside it

Ubuntu is booting fine

When I installed ubuntu I choose "Something else" and I used freespace to make partitions
I haven't touched windows partitions
I still see windows files in the file manager

**Please Help**

Comment: Probably you don't have Windows anymore. Please add output of `sudo parted -l` to your question.

Comment: Did you have any free space on your disk that was not allocated to Windows partitions? Or did you resize a Windows partition to get some free space? Did you get a choice like "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" (or any "Install Ubuntu alongside ..."), "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" and "Something else"? What did you choose? Please don't use comments to answer, [edit] your question to provide requested information.

Comment: You may have accidently deleted Windows for Ubuntu, but if you are confident, then use gparted or gnome-disk and share the screenshots of the apps.

Comment: I still have the main partitions of windows with the windows files its just not listen in grub

Comment: Does this question have the answer you need? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410398/just-installed-ubuntu-22-04-on-a-dual-boot-setup-now-my-other-os-isnt-showing

Comment: No, it is not what I needed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)