# I have too many Ubuntu boots entries, cannot reach my windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I've lost my windows and grub in  general after installing Kubuntu 22. Here is my efibootmgr entries:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0005,0006,0003
Boot0000* ubuntu        HD(2,GPT,ee4399dd-6bae-4e75-bb43-632819673924,0x1e9000,0x1e9000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0001* ubuntu        HD(2,GPT,ee4399dd-6bae-4e75-bb43-632819673924,0x1e9000,0x1e9000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0003  Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.H.i.t.a.c.h.i. .H.D.P.7.2.5.0.2.5.G.L.A.3.8.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . .E.G.2.K.4.6.T.R.M.1.4.J.A.6......AMBOAMNO........o.T.O.S.H.I.B.A. .D.T.0.1.A.C.A.0.5.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . . . .1. .2.5.B.M.8.8.S.B......AMBOAMNO........o.H.S.-.S.S.D.-.C.1.0.0. .1.2.0.G....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.3.1.0.8.8.0.6.3.2. .0. . . . . . . . ......AMBOAMNO........o.W.D.C. .W.D.1.0.E.Z.E.X.-.0.8.W.N.4.A.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . .W. .-.D.C.W.6.C.0.Y.E.V.X.8.C.5......AMBO
Boot0005  ubuntu        HD(2,GPT,ee4399dd-6bae-4e75-bb43-632819673924,0x1e9000,0x1e9000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)
Boot0006  UEFI OS       HD(2,GPT,ee4399dd-6bae-4e75-bb43-632819673924,0x1e9000,0x1e9000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)
```

I added the `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER` parameter to my grub config and ran `sudo update-grub` as suggested in the article. This is my output:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

Comment: Do the Windows partitions/files still exist on disk?  Do the Windows bootloaders still exist under /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot ?  If both exist, maybe just copy the ...Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi to ...EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and try booting the device.  Not sure why grub didn't pick up the Windows for boot though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410398/just-installed-ubuntu-22-04-on-a-dual-boot-setup-now-my-other-os-isnt-showing Also a decent part of me wonders if the UEFI OS option will boot Windows.

Comment: this is what i get when i CD into boot/efi/EFI: 

drwx------ 3 root root 4096 zan  1  1970 ../
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 me  26 08:32 BOOT/
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 me  26 08:32 ubuntu/

Comment: I have edited my question as per instructions on this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410398/just-installed-ubuntu-22-04-on-a-dual-boot-setup-now-my-other-os-isnt-showing